# Setting preloader in axios

Tags: javascript, axios

When requesting url: `/ api / v1 / todos` I set the preloader. The function `todo ()` is called inside the `todos ()` function. Inside the `todo ()` function, the request `/ api / v1 / todos / $ {todoId}` is also called. A jump occurs. The preloader appears, disappears. And then appears. How to set the preloader to appear only on the request `/ api / v1 / todos / $ {todoId}`, not `/ api / v1 / todos /`.

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function(config) {
  if (config.url === `/api/v1/todos`) {
    document.body.classList.add('preloader');
}

componentDidMOunt() {
    this.todos();
}

todos = (idGroupTasks) => {
    axios({
        url: `/api/v1/todos`,
        method: "GET"
    })
    .then(res => { 
        this.setState({
            todos: res.data
        });
        this.todo(res.data[0].id)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    }) 


}

todo = (idTodo) => {
    axios({
        url: `/api/v1/todo/{idTodo}`,
        method: "GET"
    })
    .then(res => { 
        this.setState({
            todos: res.data
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    }) 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @Nit Where does it write here about axios.interceptors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call ?

Comment: @Nit How does your article solve my problem?

Comment: Can you debug/console `config.url` and `config.baseURL` when this `/api/v1/todos/${todoId}` goes at the interceptor

Comment: @ambianBeing Inside `if` I can't

Comment: @Umbro I meant before the `if` ofcourse because your clause is based on that.

Comment: @ambianBeing before the `if` I can

Comment: @Umbro Your problem stems not from interceptors but from incorrect asynchronous flow.

Comment: @Nit I updated my answer  I  put this.todo(res.data[0].id) inside then

Comment: @Nit Advise something